# I have a mysterious <BR> being added to my table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I cant figure out why a double `<BR>` is automatically being added to my newly appended table rows.
All you have to do is hit the enter key to cause the problem.
I don't want any `<br>` to be added, it screws up my data entry process.

The problem appears to be happening in the appenNewRow() function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>jQuery Text Area Order Input</title>
      <style>
        .myInputClass {
            width: 120px;
        }
        .myOutputClass {
            width: 240px;
        }
      </style>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        storeflag = true;
        attribstart = "";
        attribend   = "";
        output_result = "";
        var row = 0;
        var storeIndex = 0;
        var productIndex = 0;
        var thisstore_id=0;

        function appendNewRow(inputType)
        {
            row++;
            var markup =  "<tr id='"+row+"'><td input-row='"+row+"' input-type='"+inputType+"' class='myInputClass' height='auto' contenteditable='true' placeholder='Next'></td><td output-row='"+row+"' class='myOutputClass'></td><td extra-row='"+row+"' class='extra'></td></tr>";
            $("table tbody").append(markup);
            myjunk = document.querySelector('[input-row="' + row + '"]').innerHTML;
            document.querySelector('[input-row="' + row + '"]').innerHTML = "zzz";
            document.getElementById(row).getElementsByClassName('myInputClass')[0].focus();


        }

        function getStore(thisstore) 
        {
        }
        function getProduct(thisstore_id, thisproduct_nickname) 
        {        
        }
      $(document).ready(function(){
        document.getElementById('1').getElementsByClassName('myInputClass')[0].focus();
        lastKey = 13; 

        $("tbody").on('keypress', ".myInputClass", (function(event){
            if (event.which == 13) {    // Enter Key.
                attribstart = "";
                attribend   = "";
                row = Number($(this).attr('input-row'));
                thishtml = $(this).html();
                if ($(this).text().length > 0) {
                    x = $(this).text();
                    if (storeflag == true) {
                        thisstore_id = getStore(x);
                    } else {
                        getProduct(thisstore_id,x); 
                    }
                } else {
                    $(this).text("---");
                    appendNewRow('store');
                    storeflag = true;
                    //$('#YourContainer').find('br').remove();
                    $('[input-row="' + row + '"]').find('br').remove(); // Fixes an ajax bug.

                }
           } else {

           } //end if
           lastKey = event.which;
        }));         
     });    
  </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table>
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Input</th>
               <th>Output</th>
               <th>Extra</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr id='1'>
                <td input-row='1' input-type='store' class='myInputClass' height='auto' contenteditable='true' placeholder='Just Start Typing a storename'></td>
                <td output-row='1' class='myOutputClass'></td>
                <td extra-row='1' class='extra'></td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's a little unclear where the issue lies. Can you share what you have tried so far? Is there a specific step that needs to be performed to replicate the issue?

Comment: When you hit the enter key without any data. The newly appended table row will contain 2 break tags.  The DOM or browser or javascript is somehow adding 2 break tags. And I cant seem to remove them via javascript.    If you can run my script, just hiy the enter key a few times and the last/current input div will contain 2 break tags.

Comment: There's way too much code in this question. Please [edit] it to narrow down the problem and provide a [**minimal**, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: From your current code, I can't reproduce anything. It's just only showing Input, Output, Extra and editable field. Fill in text and enter just showing new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleaned up the code you presented. It's a better practice to use all jQuery or all JavaScript. Based on the following testing, you may need to add the content and then make it Editable.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#empty").click(function() {
    $("<tr>").appendTo($("table tbody"));
    $("<td>").appendTo($("table tr:last")).prop("contenteditable", true);
  });
  $("#full").click(function() {
    $("<tr>").appendTo($("table tbody"));
    $("<td>").appendTo($("table tr:last")).html("Edit").prop("contenteditable", true);
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

table tr {
  height: 1.5em;
}

table tr td {
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Non-Edit</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button id="empty">Add Empty Row</button>
<button id="full">Add Full Row</button>
```

We apply this to your code.

```js
$(function() {
  var storeflag = true,
    attribstart = "",
    attribend = "",
    output_result = "",
    row = 0,
    storeIndex = 0,
    productIndex = 0,
    thisstore_id = 0;

  function appendNewRow(inputType) {
    var markRow = $("<tr>", {
      id: ++row
    }).appendTo($("table tbody"));
    $("<td>", {
      class: "myInputClass",
      height: "auto",
      placeholder: "Next",
      "input-row": row,
      "input-type": inputType
    }).appendTo(markRow);
    $("<td>", {
      class: "myOutputClass",
      "output-row": row
    }).appendTo(markRow);
    $("<td>", {
      class: "extra",
      "extra-row": row
    }).appendTo(markRow);
    $("td:eq(0)", markRow).html("Start").prop("contenteditable", true).focus();
  }

  function getStore(thisstore) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'ajax_getstore',
      data: "store=" + thisstore,
      method: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        var markup = "";
        if (data.length > 1) {
          $.each(data, function(thisname, thisvalue) {
            var output = attribstart + thisvalue.fields.name + attribend;
            markup += "<tr id='" + row + "'><td class='dyninput'>row:" + row + " - " + output + "</td></tr>";
          });
        } else {
          $('[input-row="' + row + '"]').html(thisstore); // Fixes an ajax bug.
          $('[output-row="' + row + '"]').attr('input-type', 'store');
          $('[output-row="' + row + '"]').html(attribstart + data[0].fields.name + attribend);
        }
        thisstore_id = data[0].pk;
        appendNewRow('product');
        output_result = "";
      }, // End success.
      error: function() {
        alert('error');
      },
    }); //End Ajax.
    attribstart = "<b>";
    attribend = "</b>";
    storeflag = false; //reset storeflag.
  }

  function getProduct(thisstore_id, thisproduct_nickname) {
    var qty = parseInt(thisproduct_nickname);
    if (isNaN(qty)) {
      qty = '1';
    } else {
      thisproduct_nickname = thisproduct_nickname.replace(qty, '');
    }
    $.ajax({
      url: 'ajax_getproduct',
      data: 'store_id=' + thisstore_id + '&qty=' + qty + '&product_nickname=' + thisproduct_nickname,
      method: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        var markup = "";
        if (data.length > 1) {
          $.each(data, function(thisname, thisvalue) {
            var output = attribstart + thisvalue.fields.product_name + attribend;
            markup = markup + "<tr id='" + row + "'><td class='dyninput'>row:" + row + " - " + output + "<br></td></tr>";
            row++;
          });
        } else {
          $('[input-row="' + row + '"]').html(thisproduct_nickname); // Fixes an ajax bug.
          $('[output-row="' + row + '"]').attr('input-type', 'product');
          $('[output-row="' + row + '"]').html(attribstart + qty + ' ' + data[0].fields.product_default_uom_code + ' ' + data[0].fields.product_name + attribend);
        }
        appendNewRow('product');
        output_result = "";

      }, // End success.
      error: function() {
        alert('error');
      },
    }); //End Ajax.
  }

  function display_result(data_output_result) {
    var badjson = JSON.parse(data_output_result);
    var myjson = badjson.replace("\\", "");
    var goodjson = JSON.parse(myjson);
    var markup = "";
    $.each(goodjson, function(thisname, thisvalue) {
      row = row + 1;
      var output = attribstart + thisvalue.fields.name + attribend;
      markup += "<tr id='" + row + "'><td class='dyninput'>row:" + row + " - " + output + "<br></td></tr>";
      console.log(thisvalue.fields.id, thisvalue.fields.name);
    });
    $("table tbody#myOutputBodyId").append(markup);
    output_result = "";
  }

  $('#1 .myInputClass').focus();
  var lastKey = 13;

  $("tbody").on('keypress', ".myInputClass", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.which == 13) { // Enter Key.
      attribstart = "";
      attribend = "";
      row = Number($(this).attr('input-row'));
      thishtml = $(this).html();
      if ($(this).text().length > 0) {
        x = $(this).text();
        if (storeflag == true) {
          thisstore_id = getStore(x);
        } else {
          getProduct(thisstore_id, x);
        }
      } else {
        $(this).text("---");
        appendNewRow('store');
        storeflag = true;
        //$('#YourContainer').find('br').remove();
        $('[input-row="' + row + '"]').find('br').remove(); // Fixes an ajax bug.

      }
    } //end if
    lastKey = event.which;
  });
});
```

```css
.myInputClass {
  width: 120px;
}

.myOutputClass {
  width: 240px;
}

table,
td {
  margin: 0px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 0px;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

table th {
  border: 1px solid #6C220B;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: left;
}

table#myOutputTableId {
  border: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  align: top;
}

[xcontentEditable=true]:empty:before {
  content: attr(placeholder);
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Input</th>
      <th>Output</th>
      <th>Extra</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id='1'>
      <td input-row='1' input-type='store' class='myInputClass' height='auto' contenteditable='true' placeholder='Just Start Typing a storename'></td>
      <td output-row='1' class='myOutputClass'></td>
      <td extra-row='1' class='extra'></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The issue was the key capture from the <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This was injecting the new line in the editable and creating the `<br>`. We can use `.preventDefault()` to address this.

I am unable to test this code as it does not connect to any of the AJAX Urls.

Comment: The ajax is not the issue.  So no need to hit them.  Just simply hitting the Enter Key will produce the unwanted break tags.  But you can only see them when inspecting the page.  Hit the enter key once.  The new line will contain 2 break tags and the zzz text.

Comment: I ran it.  Hit the enter key.  and produced this:   <td input-row="2" input-type="store" class="myInputClass" height="auto" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Next"><br><br>zzz</td>

Comment: So...  I'm not completely satisfied, but my current fix that works is to throw some CSS at it.
br {display:none;}   seems to do the trick.
When I call the appendNewRow() from my 2 ajax routines the row gets appended as expected.  But for some reason calling it direct causes the double break issue.

Comment: @Mike please see the updates. I found the root issue.

Comment: Twisty - Thank you! .preventDefault() seems to be working. I just needed to move it down 1 line so it doesn't prevent data from being entered. lol....